# include function results parse error in php

Tags: php, include, php-parse-error

In this following php code when I include "teacher-header.php" it encounters a error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eClassroom\teacher-dashboard.php on line 100
```

line 100 in "teacher-dashboard.php" is `<?php }?>`. What should i do?

teacher-dashboard.php

```html
<?php 

session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION['email'])) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){


?>


<?php include 'components/teacher-header.php'?>


<section class="teacher-section-area">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading overview-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Dashboard</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> 8</h2>
                            <h4>Students</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-video"></i> 12</h2>
                            <h4>Videos</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i> 5</h2>
                            <h4>Lectures</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> 3</h2>
                            <h4>ClassRooms</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading overview-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Running ClassRoom List</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="card">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">No.</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Course Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Course Code</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Action </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                    <td>Algorithm</td>
                                    <td>CSE 302</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="classrooms-files-videos.html">
                                            <i class="#"></i>View
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--col-md-9 div END-->
    </div>
    <!--row div END-->
</div>
<!--container div END-->
</section>

<?php }?>

<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php 

}
else{
    header('Location: home.php');
}

?>
```

teacher-header.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>e-ClassRoom Management System</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="teacher_panel-area panel-header-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <!--====== LOGO HERE ======-->
                            <a href="teacher-dashboard.php">
                                <p>eClassroom</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <nav class="teacher_menu adtec-menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="#">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Welcome,
                                        <Span class="teacher_name">Teacher Name</Span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="includes/logout.php">
                                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        

        <?php

        if($_SESSION['approval'] == '0'){

            echo '<div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary text-center">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Approval Notice</strong></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">Your account is waiting for admin approval. Once approved, you can avail the dashboard options.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

        }

        else{

        ?>
        
        <!-- content area start -->
        <div class="content-area">
            <!-- sidebar area start -->
            <div class="sidebar-area hidden-xs">
                <div class="sidebar-menu">
                    <div class="dashboard-name">
                        <p> Teacher Panel</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="teacher-dashboard.html"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> students </a>
                        <!-- sub menu start -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="show-all-students.html"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> show all students</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- sub menu end -->
                    </li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> ClassRooms </a>
                    <!-- sub menu start -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="create-classrooms.html"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Create  ClassRoom</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- sub menu end -->
                </li>
                
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> Assignment </a>
                <!-- sub menu start -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="show-all-assignments.html"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Show All Assignment</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- sub menu end -->
            </li>
            
            
            <li><a href="edit-teacher-profile.html"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- sidebar area end -->
</div>
<!-- content area end -->
```

Comment: `<?php include 'components/teacher-header.php'?>` - missing a `;` here and the `}else{` in `teacher-header.php` looks like it's unclosed.  I would suggest investing in an better editor like EclipsePDT Its pricey like .... `$0` USD ... lol.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing brace in teacher-header.php

Comment: You have an open curly bracket on one file, and close that on another file? that's really confusing.

Comment: remove <?php }?> curly brace.

Comment: @catcon I think the closing brace in the dashboard file is for the if at the beginning. At least, that's its intention.

Comment: In the include file I have opened a curly bracket and closed it in the main file. That's the reason why it is showing error. That closing bracket encounters an unexpected bracket. And i have tried putting a semicolon and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing brackets properly, use following and check if it works for you.

Main File:

```
<?php 

session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION['email'])) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){


?>


<?php include 'components/teacher-header.php';?>


<section class="teacher-section-area">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading overview-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Dashboard</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> 8</h2>
                            <h4>Students</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-video"></i> 12</h2>
                            <h4>Videos</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i> 5</h2>
                            <h4>Lectures</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="well dash-box">
                            <h2><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> 3</h2>
                            <h4>ClassRooms</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading overview-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Running ClassRoom List</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="card">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">No.</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Course Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Course Code</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Action </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                    <td>Algorithm</td>
                                    <td>CSE 302</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="classrooms-files-videos.html">
                                            <i class="#"></i>View
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--col-md-9 div END-->
    </div>
    <!--row div END-->
</div>
<!--container div END-->
</section>

<?php }
else
{
    header('Location: home.php');   
}
?>

<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

teacher-header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>e-ClassRoom Management System</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="teacher_panel-area panel-header-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <!--====== LOGO HERE ======-->
                            <a href="teacher-dashboard.php">
                                <p>eClassroom</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <nav class="teacher_menu adtec-menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="#">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Welcome,
                                        <Span class="teacher_name">Teacher Name</Span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="includes/logout.php">
                                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>



        <?php

        if($_SESSION['approval'] == '0'){

            echo '<div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary text-center">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Approval Notice</strong></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">Your account is waiting for admin approval. Once approved, you can avail the dashboard options.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

        }

        else{

        ?>

        <!-- content area start -->
        <div class="content-area">
            <!-- sidebar area start -->
            <div class="sidebar-area hidden-xs">
                <div class="sidebar-menu">
                    <div class="dashboard-name">
                        <p> Teacher Panel</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="teacher-dashboard.html"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> students </a>
                        <!-- sub menu start -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="show-all-students.html"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> show all students</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- sub menu end -->
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> ClassRooms </a>
                    <!-- sub menu start -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="create-classrooms.html"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Create  ClassRoom</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- sub menu end -->
                </li>

                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> Assignment </a>
                <!-- sub menu start -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="show-all-assignments.html"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Show All Assignment</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- sub menu end -->
            </li>


            <li><a href="edit-teacher-profile.html"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- sidebar area end -->
</div>
<!-- content area end -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: happy to know you issue is resolved :)